# Firestore writes inside cloud functions are significaly slower than running function locally

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Function that generates some data and stores it in my Firestore database. Some of these documents are quite large (200-500kB when saved as a regular JSON file).

My issue is, that this Function runs quite a low slower when deployed than when running it locally. Upon further investigation, it turns out that specifically, the database writes take way longer. When running my function in a local emulator but still writing the documents into the actual deploy (not emulated) database, the writes take around 1-3 seconds. When deploying my function, the writes take an average of 20-30 seconds.

I made a code snippet to reproduce my issue and benchmark the write times:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function generateTestData() {

    const object: any = {
        children: []
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        object.id = uuidv4();
        object[`attribute${i}`] = uuidv4();
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const childObject: any = {};
        for (let j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            childObject[`attribute${j}`] = uuidv4();
        }

        object.children.push(childObject);
    }

    return object;
}

async function storeTestData() {
    const items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        items.push(generateTestData());
    }

    const proms = items.map((item: any, index) => {
        const children = item.children;
        item.children = undefined;

        return [
            admin.firestore().collection("Items").doc(item.id).set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)), { merge: true }),
            admin.firestore().collection("Items").doc(item.id).collection("Children").doc("Children").set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ children: children })), { merge: true }),
        ];
    }).reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []) ?? [];

    try {
        await Promise.all(proms);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error", error);
    }

    return;

}


export const benchmarkFunctionWrites = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    const t1 = new Date().getTime();
    await storeTestData();

    console.log("Took " + (new Date().getTime() - t1) + "ms");
    res.status(200).send({ duration: (new Date().getTime() - t1) });

});
```

I benchmark this function with the following script:

```
(async () => {
    const functionUrl = "FUNCTION_URL"
    const writeDurations = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const res = await fetch(functionUrl);
        const json = await res.json();
        const duration = json.duration;
        console.log("Duration:", duration);
        writeDurations.push(duration);
    }

    console.log("Average:", writeDurations.reduce((a: any, b: any) => a + b, 0) / writeDurations.length);
})()
```

Here is an example of the output of the benchmark when run on the emulator:

```
Duration: 1047
Duration: 1079
Duration: 1566
Duration: 1591
Duration: 1612
Duration: 1856
Duration: 2570
Duration: 2238
Duration: 2933
Duration: 3690
Average: 2018.2
```

Here is an example of the benchmark when using the deployed url:

```
Duration: 33389
Duration: 26406
Duration: 24720
Duration: 33133
Duration: 24712
Duration: 28892
Duration: 24572
Duration: 32681
Duration: 27282
Duration: 24564
Average: 28035.1
```

Any help regarding this issue is highly appreciated!

---

Edit: As to Doug Stevenson's recommendation of running the benchmark writes sequentially multiple time in the same function, I updated my benchmark like this:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function generateTestData() {

    const object: any = {
        children: []
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        object.id = uuidv4();
        object[`attribute${i}`] = uuidv4();
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        const childObject: any = {};
        for (let j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
            childObject[`attribute${j}`] = uuidv4();
        }

        object.children.push(childObject);
    }

    return object;
}

async function storeTestData() {
    const items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        items.push(generateTestData());
    }

    const proms = items.map((item: any, index) => {
        const children = item.children;
        item.children = undefined;

        return [
            admin.firestore().collection("Items").doc(item.id).set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)), { merge: true }),
            admin.firestore().collection("Items").doc(item.id).collection("Children").doc("Children").set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ children: children })), { merge: true }),
        ];
    }).reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []) ?? [];

    try {
        await Promise.all(proms);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error", error);
    }

    return;

}


export const benchmarkFunctionWrites = functions.region('europe-west3').https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    const results: number[] = [];

    async function benchmarkCycle() {
        try {
            const t1 = new Date().getTime();
            await storeTestData();
            results.push(new Date().getTime() - t1);
            console.log("Took " + (new Date().getTime() - t1) + "ms");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    await benchmarkCycle();
    await benchmarkCycle();
    await benchmarkCycle();
    await benchmarkCycle();
    await benchmarkCycle();

    res.status(200).send({ durations: results });

});

export const benchmarkFunctionWritesUs = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    const t1 = new Date().getTime();
    await storeTestData();

    console.log("Took " + (new Date().getTime() - t1) + "ms");
    res.status(200).send({ duration: (new Date().getTime() - t1) });

});
```

Note I have decreased the size of the generated test data, because I was getting some other errors (13 INTERNAL: Received RST_STREAM with code 2) that are not subject of this question. This results in proportionately faster writes but the original issue is still the case.

Here is an example run with the deployed function

```
Durations: [ 14136, 6731, 6789, 6587, 6291 ]
Durations: [ 12208, 7290, 7793, 7352, 6800 ]
Durations: [ 6821, 6670, 6476, 6820, 6420 ]
Durations: [ 6442, 6892, 5905, 6411, 6708 ]
Durations: [ 6384, 6871, 6058, 6654, 6278 ]
Durations: [ 7898, 7196, 6969, 6805, 6921 ]
Durations: [ 6116, 6507, 6508, 6721, 6871 ]
Durations: [ 6987, 6876, 6053, 6346, 6936 ]
Durations: [ 6253, 7295, 6128, 6282, 6812 ]
Durations: [ 6967, 6870, 6428, 6682, 6371 ]
Average: 6951.7
```

Here is an example run with the emulated function

```
Durations: [ 4274, 962, 987, 936, 960 ]
Durations: [ 976, 1029, 944, 914, 935 ]
Durations: [ 986, 955, 947, 1003, 950 ]
Durations: [ 1052, 908, 909, 918, 904 ]
Durations: [ 945, 918, 1054, 892, 929 ]
Durations: [ 933, 910, 1086, 918, 970 ]
Durations: [ 933, 949, 915, 903, 919 ]
Durations: [ 945, 952, 1015, 936, 899 ]
Durations: [ 925, 895, 1009, 966, 945 ]
Durations: [ 939, 909, 960, 960, 907 ]
Average: 1015.7
```

Comment: Run the function, in the production environment, `n` times every `t` seconds and observe the execution time in the GCC Logs Explorer. You should see execution time exponentially decrease as `n` increases. Gen 2 functions in GCF can be configured quite nicely to meet this specific function's needs, such as max and min instances, concurrency allowances, memory allocation, and CPU allocation. If this is a function that should always have low execution time at all times, you may need to keep it warm through configuration.

Comment: @trndjc I made a benchmark script that runs the function 10 times. I measure only the time it takes to write the documents to Firestore so I assume I can exclude the possibility that it's due to cold start of the functions

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, comparing the performance of the emulator vs. the actual cloud service is not really a fair proposition.  The emulator is nothing more than a very simple approximation of the behavior of the cloud service, and doesn't have any of the same performance of scalability or performance characteristics.  It's completely different code running on completely different hardware.

In your question, you haven't said how you're benchmarking this code, so I'm going to take a guess and say that you're observing the effect of "cold starts" in Cloud Functions.  This is a very well known and [well documented](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) issue and I won't bother repeating any of the details here - you can do a web search for "Cloud Functions cold starts" to learn more.

What I would suggest, if you're interested in understanding the behavior of only the document writes and not the entire Cloud Functions system, then write lines of code to benchmark and log only those writes and nothing else. In general I would expect reads and writes entirely within the Google Cloud Platform to be faster than those coming from outside (including your personal machine).  But you need those specific benchmarks to observe this for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Doug Stevenson. I benchmark my code by looking at the timestamp before making my Firestore writes and after, meaning I benchmark only the writes and nothing else, not the entire function run. Therefore I think the comparison between local and cloud runs is not entirely unfair, furthermore, I think it's safe to assume the problem is not down to cold starts as this should not reflect the performance of Firestore writes, right?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the minimal complete reproducible code you used, including the benchmarks and the output.  We should be able to copy what you have and run it for ourselves to observe the same result.

Comment: Added more information with reproducible code

Comment: Please share the actual perf output. Run the function multiple times in sequence and show that the times have consistency beyond the expected delays of first-time startup costs.

Comment: Added a benchmark script that calls the function 10 times, the difference is clearly visible between emulator and deployed function and due to only measuring the database writes I think it's safe to dismiss the possibility that the difference is due to startup time

Comment: You're showing the *external* benchmarks, which includes a round trip between your machine and the remote function.  That's *always* going to cost more than running a local emulator, especially if you're not geographically close to the function deployment.  You need to show the cost of just the queries running inside the function without the overhead of the function invocation and network round trip.

Comment: If you want to understand the pure function overhead of the invocation without the queries, make a function that does nothing but send back a 200 response and benchmark it - that's the cost of "doing business" with the function from the client's point of view. It will vary wildly based on the geographic separation and quality of network between them.

Comment: In the function `benchmarkFunctionWrites` I measure the duration only for the Firestore writes. I then return this duration in my response from the Function and use exactly this duration to calculate my average write duration in my benchmark script. To my understanding, this is exactly what you are describing, I'm not measuring the time it takes for my client to reach out to the Function or the Function the return a response. I am just sending a 200 response in addition to the duration value.

Comment: Instead of invoking the function n times, run the benchmark within a single function invocation n times.  Each function invocation will still have some internal first-time startup costs related to the code it has to load and execute on a cold start.  Your current benchmark strategy isn't currently aware of any aspect of coldness or warmness of the function, or have any awareness of how many server instances are being managed by the invocations.  You could also invoke the function a number of time in addition to that.

Comment: You should also note which region your function was deployed to and which region your Firestore database is in.  Ideally they should be in the same region for minimum latency.  If they are in different regions, you're paying a much larger round trip cost than necessary for each and every query.

Comment: Indeed, my Functions and Firestore were not deployed in the same region. I have changed that and the benchmarks improve by 2-4 seconds but the average duration is still around 20 sec. longer than when run on an emulator. I feel like this duration is still unreasonably long

Comment: Did you try my latest recommendation?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and yes, I only saw your second comment. I tried making multiple sequential writes in my benchmark (see my question edit with the updated benchmark). The issue is still the case. All  Firestore writes take much longer in the deployed version than in the local version (not just the first one).  For some reason, the first write of the first cloud function call takes even longer than the others (both deployed and emulated), probably due to some startup but that is not the problem I'm having.

Comment: The first Firestore write for a server instance has the overhead of establishing a socket connection. That's why a good benchmark will do several writes repeatedly in one call.

Comment: I understand this but I would expect that the remaining writes with my deployed function are more similar in speed as to when I run my function on a local emulator  (while writing to the production Firestore database). This is clearly not the case. Is there any way to speed this up, I feel like it shouldn't be that slow